# Android rounded border color top-left only dinamically

Tags: android, gridview, layout, rounded-corners, border-layout

I need to set dynamically a GridView item, I am using LinearLayout with background drawable applying round corners but I can't figure out to set only top-left border color like this picture....
[image: Example]

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8lyH.png"/>
```

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/gridview_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/griditem_cat" />
    <padding android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: you want to set that top left corner color dyanmically or you have this four color only?

Comment: @Aditya Vyas-Lakhan It need to be dynamically colored with hexadecimal colors, I AM trying with triangle custom views but I Lost the rounded top left corner like the image example attached

Comment: if dynamically, you need to call `Drawable#setColorFilter` on your "triangle" drawable

Comment: @pskink I will try setting triangle color...

Comment: As I said using triangle I can set color with a custom view (http://imgur.com/a/3i2JB) but I didn`t found how to make it rounded top-left
``

Answer (score 0):

**grid_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/gridview_item" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <PinnedGridItemView 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/gridview_text">
     </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**CategoryAdapter**

```
pin = (PinnedGridItemView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.pinned_grid_item);
pin.setColorCode(Color.RED);// Here I set any color that I want dynamically, the problem now is to solve top-left rounded corner
```

[image: Result image]